# How can I write in a compact way $v_j = \max_i Q_{i,j}$ without using indexes?

Tags: matrices, optimization, notation

Let $Q$ be a matrix. I would like to write in a compact way (without indexing) $$\max_i Q_{*,i}$$ that should return a vertical vector $$v_j = \max_i Q_{j,i}$$

I need it because I have

$$Q = R + \gamma P \max_i Q_{*,i}$$

and I would like to have a matrix notation where there are no indexes. Now in my document I wrote something like

$$Q = R + \gamma P Q^*$$

making clear that $Q^* = \max_i Q_{*,i}$. But, if I find a more appropriate way to write this "operator" it will be great!
(Q is a matrix, R is a matrix, P is a 3-d matrix)

Comment: Maximization of *what* of a matrix?

Comment: Sorry I thought that the formula was self-explicative. I would like to have a vertical vector where each position i^th of this vector is the highest value of the i^th row of the matrix

Comment: It would be helpful to Readers to have the explanation of your notion of "maximization of a Matrix" added to the body of your Question.  You may have thought "the formula was self-explicative" but your concept is closer to an "arg max" than it is to a maximum value.

Comment: okay, by the way, do you know a better way to denote such operation?

Comment: do you think now the question is clearer?

Comment: The formula didn't make sense because there's no range on $i$ and the asterisk isn't defined. Now that you've clarified what you mean, it seems the $i$ will range from $1$ to $m$ where $m$ is the # of rows, and the * is an arbitrary placeholder for the column index, but then what's written is sort of backwards. And the asterisk is not really used that way in math. It sounds like you have a matrix $Q \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and want a vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $v_i = \displaystyle \max_{1 \le j \le n} Q_{i, j}$ for $1 \le i \le m$. There's not really a way to write it w/o indexing.

Comment: Okay, thanks (you are right, I exchanged the indexes)

Comment: And just another question. If I have 3D matrix, and I multiply it on the right for a classical vertical vector will I have a classical 2D matrix right?